# Rules based data transformation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is an example data frame:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(Name_current = c("John", "John", "John", 
"Clark", "Paul", "John", "Beth", "Beth", "Clark", "Betty", "Paul",
 "John", "Clark", "Betty", "John"), Membership_current = c("red", 
"red", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white", "green", "blue", 
"white", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "green"), Customer = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15"), Group_ID = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "7", "8", "6", "8", 
"3", "7", "5", "2", "3"), Name_new = c("Clark", "Paul", "John", 
"Beth", "Clark", "John", "Clark", "Betty", "John", "John", "John", 
"Clark", "Paul", "John", "Betty"), Membership_new = c("red", "blue", 
"green", "blue", "white", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "red", 
"blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white"), Category1 = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), Category2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE), Category3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The challenge is to rearrange the data according to two given rules:

**1st rule:**
As soon as a `TRUE` occurs in one of the three category columns (`Category1/2/3`), the associated name and membership from the columns `Name_current` & `Membership_current` should be transferred to the columns `Name_new` & `Membership_new` and for all other entries that belong to the same group (`Group_ID`).

**2nd rule:**
For the remaining entries where the first rule is not applied, the number of the same `Name_current` per `Group_ID` must be determined. If a name occurs more than 75% times, then `Name_current` and the associated `Membership_current` should be transferred to the `Name_new` and `Membership_new` columns.

The result data frame needs to have only one entry per `Group-ID` and only with the entries where changes were made. Only the columns `Group_ID`, `Name_new` and `Membership_new` are required.

Until now I only managed to get the number of `Name_current` grouped by `Group_ID`.

`df1 <-  df1 %>% group_by(Group_ID) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(Name_current))`

Does anyone have an elegant solution to solve both rules?

**Update:**
This would be the expected output of the example data frame:

According to the **first rule** (a TRUE occurs in one of the categories columns):

```
Group_ID , Name_new , Membership_new  
3 , Paul , blue  
5 , Clark , red  
7 , Beth , white
```

And for the other `Group_ID`s would be the output as followed according to **rule 2** (a name occurs more than 75% within the same `Group_ID`):

```
Group_ID , Name_new , Membership_new  
2 , John , red  
6 , Clark, blue  
8 , Betty , white
```

The complete output as a data frame would be like `df2`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Group_ID = c("3", "5", "7", "2", "6", "8"), 
 Name_new = c("Paul", "Clark", "Beth", "John", "Clark", "Betty"), 
Customer = c("blue", "red", "white", "red", "blue", "white"), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I hope the example clarifies the problem a little bit more

Comment: This isn't super clear. Could you maybe show the expected output for the sample input? And address some specific questions: in **rule 1** when you say *"and for all other entries that belong to the same group (Group_ID)"* what do you mean? Are "all other entries" entries that come after the condition being met? Or is it literally all entries in the group if the condition is ever met in the group? Or something else?

Comment: *"The result data frame needs to have only one entry per Group-ID and only with the entries where changes were made."* In **Rule 1** and **Rule 2** it sounds like you want to change multiple entries per Group. So now it is really confusing when you way the result should have only one entry per Group-ID.

Comment: I can give a start of code - to identify the rows after any of the Category columns flip to TRUE, use `df1 %>%
  group_by(Group_ID) %>%
  mutate(rule1 = cumsum(Category1 | Category2 | Category3) > 1)`, but I am too confused by your description to continue any more.

Comment: Thanks, rather than answering down here in comments where the formatting is hard to read, please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @GregorThomas Does the example output help? Is there more information you need?

Comment: Ok, based on your example output it seems like by "rearrange the data" you mean "extract one row that meet these rules and put them in a new data frame". Does that sound right?

Comment: @GregorThomas Yes, that's correct. Sorry for the mix-up.

Answer (score 1):

As [Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor-thomas) pointed out in his comments, this isn't clear at all. I interpreted Gregor's concern to **rule 1** as "literally all entries in the group if the condition is ever met in the group." Furthermore, the condition with the 75% in **rule 2** is also unclear, so I interpreted it as "if the count of `Name_current` per `Group_ID` (in the complement of **rule 1**) relatively to the count of `Name_current` (in the complement of **rule 1**) is greater than 75%." So here is my solution, where 11 out of 15 rows are affected by **rules 1 and 2** (customer nr. 4, 9, 10 and 14 are not affected):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(
  Name_current = c("John", "John", "John", "Clark", "Paul", "John", "Beth", "Beth", "Clark", "Betty", "Paul", "John", "Clark", "Betty", "John"), 
  Membership_current = c("red", "red", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white", "green", "blue", "white", "blue", "red", "red", "blue", "green"), 
  Customer = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"), 
  Group_ID = c("2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "7", "8", "6", "8", "3", "7", "5", "2", "3"), 
  Name_new = c("Clark", "Paul", "John", "Beth", "Clark", "John", "Clark", "Betty", "John", "John", "John", "Clark", "Paul", "John", "Betty"), 
  Membership_new = c("red", "blue", "green", "blue", "white", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "red", "blue", "green", "blue", "yellow", "white"), 
  Category1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
  Category2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), 
  Category3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

first_rule_group_ids <- df1 %>% filter(
  # if any of Category1 to Category 3 is TRUE
  Category1 + Category2 + Category3 > 0
) %>% pull(
  # take the whole group, i.e.
  # "literally all entries in the group if the condition is ever met in the group."
  Group_ID
)

df_result <- df1 %>% mutate(
  # bring *_current to *_new whenever rule 1 holds,
  # where * = {Name, Membership}
  Name_new = ifelse(Group_ID %in% first_rule_group_ids, Name_current, Name_new),
  Membership_new = ifelse(Group_ID %in% first_rule_group_ids, Membership_current, Membership_new),
  # keep track of changes
  changed = ifelse(Group_ID %in% first_rule_group_ids, TRUE, FALSE)
)

second_rule_names_and_group_ids <- df1 %>% filter(
  # complement of rule 1, i.e. not rule 1
  !(Group_ID %in% first_rule_group_ids)
) %>% group_by(
  # here the order of grouping is crucial, since we want Group_ID to be
  # dropped after summarise (count of Name_current in Group_ID vs count of
  # Name_current not in Group_ID)
  Name_current,
  Group_ID
) %>% summarise(
  # count of a name in a group, for example John occurs 6 times in the 
  # original df1, but only 3 times here in the complement of rule 1, 
  # and all 3 occurrences here are in group 2, therefore the quotient here
  # is 100% > 75% and those 3 entries get changed
  cnt_name_in_group = n()
) %>% mutate(
  cnt_total = sum(cnt_name_in_group),
  prct = cnt_name_in_group / cnt_total
) %>% filter(
  prct > 0.75
) %>% select(
  Name_current,
  Group_ID
) %>% mutate(
  # add column Name_new for left_join below
  Name_new = Name_current
)

df_result <- df_result %>% left_join(
  # renames Name_new of df_result to Name_new.x and adds column
  # Name_new of second_rule_names_and_group_ids as Name_new.y
  second_rule_names_and_group_ids, 
  by = c("Name_current", "Group_ID")
) %>% mutate(
  Name_new.x = ifelse(is.na(Name_new.y), Name_new.x, Name_new.y),
  Membership_new = ifelse(is.na(Name_new.y), Membership_new, Membership_current),
  # keep track of changes
  changed = ifelse(is.na(Name_new.y), changed, TRUE)
) %>% select(
  -Name_new.y
) %>% rename(
  Name_new = Name_new.x
) 

df_result %>% filter(changed)

# which is the same as:
# df_result %>% filter(
#   Group_ID %in% first_rule_group_ids |
#     (!(Group_ID %in% first_rule_group_ids) & 
#        Name_current %in% second_rule_names_and_group_ids$Name_current &
#        Group_ID %in% second_rule_names_and_group_ids$Group_ID)
# )
```

Comment: Nice answer! But don't post code like `rm(list = ls())` in questions or answers unless it is absolutely necessary. Nobody wants to accidentally run that line and lose a bunch of work in progress--especially new users getting help on Stack Overflow who might now know what it does and be very surprised and disappointed at the result.

Comment: Thank you @GregorThomas, this is my first SO answer whatsoever. The reason I put `rm(list = ls())` there is because I wanted to make the answer self contained in the sense that no other variables in the environment falsify my code. But this would not be the case anyway. Thanks for editing my answer, too.